# Call function with less numbers of arguments than function needs

Tags: solidity

I tried to call function from first contract:

```
someClass.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value)
```

tokenFallback contains with realiztion in second contract:

```
function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data)
```

I got transaction revert.
I tried to call function tokenFallback with 2 arguments on second contract:

```
function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value)
```

I got normal transaction and transfer.
How to call functions that have different numbers of argument?
Is it realy?

Comment: Non-supplied arguments are defaulted to "zero" (or the equivalent for their types). I'm pretty sure that in later versions of web3, this is no longer feasible (i.e., wb3 throws an error).